# In Google Sheets, can I query sheets from the current workbook as well as sheets from a second workbook together in the same array?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a formula that currently queries four sheets in the same workbook:

`=IFNA(QUERY({'Sheet1'!A2:J;'Sheet2'!A2:J;'Sheet3'!A2:J;'Sheet4'!A2:J},"select Col2,Col5, ...`

I want to add a fifth sheet into the array that's actually kept in another workbook. As much as it would solve all my problems, I can't bring the data into the same workbook as the other sheets due to privacy/permissions issues. I've tried doing this:

`=IFNA(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("<url>","'New Sheet'!A2:J");'Sheet1'!A2:J;'Sheet2'!A2:J;'Sheet3'!A2:J;'Sheet4'!A2:J},"select Col2,Col5, ...`

... but it gives me an error "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: lower takes a text parameter."

Is there any way to incorporate an importrange into the sheets array of a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**01 -** Paste this in a **separate cell** first and allow access.

```
IMPORTRANGE("<url>","'New Sheet'!A2:J")
```

**02 -** and then your formula

```
=IFNA(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("<url>","'New Sheet'!A2:J");
            'Sheet1'!A2:J;
            'Sheet2'!A2:J;
            'Sheet3'!A2:J;
            'Sheet4'!A2:J},"select Col2,Col5,...
```

If that doesn't work, try using `UPPER` or nested `LOWER(LOWER())` instead of `LOWER` elsewhere in your formula.